Detect scroll inside iframe in InAppWebView
I'm using the onScrollChanged callback:
onScrollChanged: (controller, x, y) {
  final pxRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
  context.read<AppData>().scroll.add(
    ScrollData(
      scrollProgress: y / pxRatio,
      timestamp: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  );

}
But InAppWebView only defines the main scroll. That is, in applications such as Miro or Figma, the scroll will not be detected. Also, this will not work, for example, in the burger menu of the site if it has a scroll. How can I detect scrolls in such cases?

I am using onScrollChanged and onOverScrolled and didn't face any issues with these on detecting the scroll event. If you have any problems please update the question.

@mattyman tell me please which version of lib are you using?
